# Python, multiple screen shots using PhantomJS

Tags: python

Multiple screenshots expected but I get only the first one.
Here is my code that I tried

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    client_urls = 
    ['https://www.facebook.com/','http://www.https://stackoverflow.com']
    for client_url in client_urls:
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
        driver.get(client_url)
        print(client_url)
        screen = client_urls  
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file('C:\\Users\\xyz\\output\\b.png')
        driver.quit()'''
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is the address for stackoverflow is wrong.

Try something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
for client_url in client_urls:
    driver.get(client_url)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('C:\\Users\\xyz\\output\\'+client_url+'.png')
driver.quit()
```

I would also look into PIL if you want to join the images into one single image.